# How to route a child component to another child component

Tags: angular, routes, components

I have two child component in my project google an dpikachu.

I need to route the google page (when i clic on a button next) to the other child component pikachu.

this is my app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PikachuComponent } from './pikachu/pikachu.component';
import { GoogleComponent } from './google/google.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'google', component: GoogleComponent },
  { path: 'pikachu', component: PikachuComponent  },
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

this is my app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PikachuComponent } from './pikachu/pikachu.component';
import { GoogleComponent } from './google/google.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PikachuComponent,
    GoogleComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

any help please

Comment: Just read about routing in angular docs, you can inject a `Router` service in your component and use `navigateTo()` method, you can also use `routerLink` directive in your view to achieve your requirement

Comment: I'm already using the routerLink

<a target="_blank" rel="noopener" routerLink="/pikachu"> <button class="btn-primary">Next</button></a>

but not working, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try doing this.

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router  } from '@angular/router';

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

navigateToChild(){
   this.router.navigate(['./pikachu'], { relativeTo: this.route });
}
```

then

```
 <a target="_blank" rel="noopener" (click)="navigateToChild()"> <button class="btn-primary">Next</button></a>
```

Comment: Thank you

I added this

 constructor(private route:ActivatedRoute,private router:Router) { }
 navigateToChild(){
  this.router.navigate(['./pikachu'], { relativeTo: this.router });
} 

but is has problem with private router:Router, he cannot find the Router

Comment: Try to add `import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';` in the imports

Comment: @sr123 Please upvote and mark my answer if this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the AppRoutingModule imports into `app.module.ts`?

`@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],`

Comment: @sr123 can you post a stackblitz link with all your code?